# How to add a template dynamically after applyBindings has been called in Knockout js

Tags: templates, knockout.js

I am using Knockout JS in my project. I want to include a template after all the bindings are applied.

Example:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="ko.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<h2>Participants</h2>
<button onClick="addOnRuntime()">Insert</button>
<div id="ab">Click Me</div>

Here are the participants:
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: buyer }"></div>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: seller }"></div>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: killer }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="person-template">
<h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
   <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span></p>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function MyViewModel() {
     this.buyer = { name: 'Franklin', credits: 250 };
     this.seller = { name: 'Mario', credits: 5800 };
     this.killer = { name: 'Dj', credits: 10000 };
 }
 ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
 function addOnRuntime()
 {
     $.ajax({
        dataType:'script',
        url:'/ab.html',
        error:function(jsc){
            var temp=document.getElementById("person-template");
            temp.innerHTML=jsc.responseText;
            ko.cleanNode(temp);
            ko.applyBindings(MyViewModel(),temp);
        },
        success:function(res){
        }
     });
 }
</script>
```

I want to inject an html within the above block. But when I inject html within it there is no change taking place. I googled a lot and saw that we need to first unbind knockout by using `ko.cleanNode(viewModel)` and then again apply bindings using `ko.applyBindings(viewmodel)`, but still no change.

This is the html that is getting injected

```html
<h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1>
<p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span></p>
```

This is how it looks after injection of code

```html
<script id="person-template" type="text/html">
   <h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1>
   <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span></p>
</script>
```

Comment: Are you creating a whole new `<script>` block, or are you changing one that was already there when you first called `applyBindings`?

Comment: i was initially trying to create the whole script block but later I tried to just inject the html

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you, because I ran into the same issue recently and couldn't figure it out, but I hope someone else can. When you try to use the template that you have added dynamically, do you get any Javascript errors from Knockout? Could you check in the developer console of your browser?

Comment: It would help if you extend your sample code into an SSCE. Currently it's really rather broad and vague, and I'm afraid that if I invest in creating an answer there will pop up an "oh but in my case I can't do that because..." response. Some more details would definitely help.

Comment: keep the template there , in ajax response apply the data based on result.

Comment: Instead of changing an already applied template,perhaps you could add a new template to the DOM and change which template is used to render the items you want to change? You could easily achieve this by providing an observable to the template name selector. I wrote a quick sample at http://jsfiddle.net/bb4hhu99/, which creates a new template and changes which template is used after 3 seconds. Dynamically choosing the template for the template binding is mentiond in the documentation at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-5-dynamically-choosing-which-template-is-used.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do such a thing... If it's not 'easy' to do in Knockout there are probably other means to achieve this. One direction I'm thinking of is custom component (template) loaders. Perhaps tell us the reason why you need it to be injected *per se* after data is bound?

Comment: I feel Robert's Example is doing Exactly what i need

Answer (score 0):

Try using ko.applyBindingsToDescendants  or ko.applyBindingsToNode to newly added html. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html